# Homotopy class of $CP^2$ to $S^4$

Tags: algebraic-topology

I was doing a classification problem which ultimately boils down to determining the homotopy class from $CP^2$ to $S^4$. Maybe I can just leave it like that but is there anyway to explicitly determine all homotopy classes from $CP^2$ to $S^4$? Of course we can use cellular approximation, but is there anything else we can say? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can't you classify these based on their CW-complexes? Both have a very simple structure as CW-complexes.

Comment: Both spaces are 4-dimensional oriented manifolds, so you can use the Hopf degree theorem. Homtopy classes are classifed by their degree and there are $\mathbb{Z}$ of them.

Comment: Do you know about Eilenberg-MacLane spaces ? If you do, you can prove using cellular approximation that $[\mathbb CP^2, S^4] \cong H^4(\mathbb CP^2, \mathbb Z)$, so you just have to compute this cohomology group

Comment: @quarague I feel like this needs far more specificity. $S^n ,S^m$ have very simple CW structures but good luck computing the classes of maps between them.

Comment: @Max I do not follow your argument at all. Can you eplain? $S^4$ is not at all $K(\mathbb Z,4)$.

Comment: @AndresMejia : it's not $K(\mathbb Z,4)$, but it's bot too far from it : you can get a $K(\mathbb Z, 4)$ from by adding $6$-cells and higher dimensional cells. In particular, to the eyes of $4$ (and lower)-dimensional CW complexes, by cellular approximation $S^4$ looks just like a $K(\mathbb Z, 4)$ : making that precise gets you the isomorphism I mentioned